# Get enum value as Int in swift

Tags: swift, enums

How to get enum Int value in swift

Create Enum

```
enum FriendActionType:Int {    
    case sendFriendRequest = 1, cancelFriendRequest, acceptFriendRequest, removeFromFriendList, deleteFriendRequest
}
```

Print without hash (Perfect pass variable)

```
po "\(friendActionType)"
"deleteFriendRequest"
```

Print HashValue Log (Print wrong int value '-1188319181990702728' instead of '5')

```
po friendActionType.hashValue
-1188319181990702728
```

I want `Int` '5' value from enum variable.

Comment: Don't confuse `hashValue` and `rawValue`.

Comment: @rmaddy ok got it :) print `friendActionType.rawValue`

Answer (score 4):

Use friendActionType.rawValue

example of rawvalue

```
 enum Planet: Int {
        case mercury = 1, venus, earth, mars, jupiter, saturn, uranus, neptune
    }
    let earthsOrder = Planet.earth.rawValue
    // earthsOrder is 3
```